# mysql query retrieval missing one row

Tags: php, mysql

i have retrieve data from database with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM news, necat
WHERE news.ns_cat = necat.nc_id 
ORDER BY ns_id DESC
LIMIT 0,4
```

and when this query run return only 3 row?!
can you find any problem?

Comment: How many common records are there in those tables?

Comment: create a fiddle at www.sqlfiddle.com and then post your question with link to that fiddle

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT limits the number of possible results, but if your query only returns 3 results, it cannot extend it :)